# "Users/(Voters|Editors)" subsubmenu page selector borks subsubmenu on per-site metas

Tags: bug, user-interface

Click "Users". Click "voters" or "editors". Click a time span. Click a page number. For me, this makes the time span subsubmenu go back to it's default "all time" state. Could not reproduce on MSE or main sites.

Comment: It looks like all per-site Metas don't seem to add the `filter` variable back into the URL when changing the page.